# ckeditor-duplicated-modules Error testing CKeditor 5 plugin locally

Tags: npm, ckeditor, dependency-management

I have an editor created using the [CKEditor online builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/). besides that, [I have created a plugin](https://github.com/JoSSte/CKEditor5-variables-plugin/tree/feature/basicVariablePlugin) which I would like to use with this editor.

In order to test out my plugin, I have Done the following:

1. Executed `npm link` in the **plugin** source folder
2. Executed `npm link ckeditor5-variables-plugin` in the **editor** source folder. *As described [here](https://flaviocopes.com/npm-local-package/)*
3. Deleted `node_modules` folder from **both** sources
4. Executed `npm install` in the **editor** source folder (*this populates `node_modules` in both folders btw*)
5. Executed `npm ls` in the **plugin** source folder - no issues
6. Executed `npm ls` in the **editor** source folder - several extraneous entries
7. Executed `webpack --mode production` in the **editor** source folder  - no issues
8. Opened the `sample/index.html` file in a browser - this gives

> CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated.

No matter how or what I change, I can't get rid of this. I have followed all the guides in the [read more](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules) link provided with the error. As I see it, the issue is the several includes in npm issue, coupled with npm's inability to dedupe the packages when it is a `devDependencies` entry... moving all the `devDependencies` into `dependencies` in the **editor** did nothing to change it...

I have tried `ncu -u` and `npm dedupe` as well with no luck. Any help or advice is appreciated.

### Editor package.json devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^21.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin": "^21.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing": "^20.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "ckeditor5-variables-plugin": "file:../../ckeditor5-variables"
  }
```

### Plugin package.json Dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^20.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "^20.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^21.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin": "^21.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: Did you fix this ?

Comment: not really. I solved my own problem by extedning the "sample" editor  in the repo, but that does not fix this issue, so  it is still unpublishable